# Automatic image zoom without touching the screen

Tags: android, image, zooming

I want to **zoom an image automatically** without touching the screen.

I.e. the image must be zoomed in as soon as the activity starts **without any touch** from the user.

Answer (score 5):

Inside onCreate of MainActivity class you should define AnimationUtils and load the Animation on image view to whom you want to zoom Automatically.
 Now make an xml class inside the anim and declare the xml inside load animation as second parameter.
this is the Java Class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.zoom);
      image.startAnimation(animation1);
   }
}
```

This is the Anim xlm for zoom animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:fromXScale="0.5"
      android:toXScale="3.0"
      android:fromYScale="0.5"
      android:toYScale="3.0"
      android:duration="5000"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%" >
   </scale>

   <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:startOffset="5000"
      android:fromXScale="3.0"
      android:toXScale="0.5"
      android:fromYScale="3.0"
      android:toYScale="0.5"
      android:duration="5000"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%" >
   </scale>

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html). It will really help you. Just try to understand the whole program and you'll be able to achieve what you want. I just did! Don't call the zoomImageFromThumb method from any touch or click event. You can call it from any other event, such as you want to call at the activity startup, you can call it in onCreate method. It will work.